# How to implement polling in Robot Framework

Tags: python, robotframework

I am new to Robot Framework.
I have a test case which performs below steps
1. Connects to the DB
2. Submits a job to a server
3. Once the Job is completed a status is updated in the Job table `Job Completed`
4. Once the Job table is updated to status `Job Completed` want to check the other values in other tables in the DB

Right now i have introduced sleep after step 2 which i want to avoid. Sometimes the job might take 5 minutes to complete and sometimes 2 minutes.
How can i go ahead and add the polling in this case. I do not want to hard code sleep in this case.

Below is my piece of code

```
*** Settings ***

Suite Setup          Connect To DB
Suite Teardown       Disconnect From DB

*** Test Cases ***
TC1
    [Tags]  Debug
    log to console  Test1
    Submit The Job
    sleep  5 minutes
    ${queryResults}=  DB.query  SELECT status FROM job_table WHERE job_id=1;
    Verify Other Table Values
```

Answer (score 2):

The two keywords which i can suggest is

> **Run Keyword and Return Status**
>
> **wait until keyword succeeds**

I just modified your code little bit , to make it more explanatory

```
*** Settings ***

*** Test Cases ***
TC1
    [Tags]  Debug
    log to console  Test1
    ${success} =  Run Keyword and Return Status  Submit The Job      #Code will not switch to next keyword untill this keyword return the satus as True or False
    log  ${success}
    wait until keyword succeeds  2x  200ms  Submit The Job     #This Kw will run the KW 2 times if  KW fails   while waiting 200ms after each result

*** Keywords ***
Submit The Job
    Sleep  5s
```

More details about these keywords can be found from [Built in KW](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html)